# Нужна ли запятая в обороте "то пусто(,) то густо"?

Tags: пунктуация

Вроде бы, в устойчивых оборотах запятые не нужны, но в обороте "то пусто(,) то густо" она очень просится. Или это мне только кажется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что здесь нужна запятая, так как это выражение нельзя заменить одним словом (как, например, "и день и ночь": т. е. постоянно, непрерывно). http://www.slovoborg.ru/definition/%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%2C+%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с inna. Фразеологизмы бывают разные. Типы фразеологизмов (фразеологические сращения, единства и сочетания ) различаются степенью спаянности элементов. Запятая не ставится ставится во  фразеологических оборотах, равных по значению одному слову.